# detach rectangle from scaling and give it "absolute" coordinates, or autoscale the rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

This is the layout I am trying to achieve:
[image: My Plot]
I actually manage to do this with this code:

```py
def create_bcs_plot(x_data: tuple = tuple(), y_data: tuple = tuple()):
    # initialize figure
    fig = Figure(figsize=(7, 6))
    axs = fig.subplots()
    minx, maxx, midx = 0, 1, 0.5
    miny, maxy, midy = 0, 1, 0.5
    offsetx, offsety = 0.1, 0.1
    axs.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((minx, maxy), maxx, offsety, fill=False, edgecolor="black", clip_on=False, lw=0.5))
    axs.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((maxx, miny), offsetx, maxy, fill=False, edgecolor="black", clip_on=False, lw=0.5))

    # colored boxes inside plot
    axs.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((minx, midy), midx, midy, alpha=0.1, facecolor="green"))
    axs.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((midx, midy), midx, midy, alpha=0.1, facecolor="yellow"))
    axs.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((minx, miny), midx, midy, alpha=0.1, facecolor="gray"))
    axs.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((midx, miny), midx, midy, alpha=0.1, facecolor="red"))

    # crossed lines that separate the four classes
    axs.add_line(Line2D(xdata=(minx, maxx + offsetx), ydata=(midy, midy), clip_on=False, color="black", lw=0.5))
    axs.add_line(Line2D(xdata=(midx, midx), ydata=(miny, maxy + offsety), clip_on=False, color="black", lw=0.5))

    # y-axis HIGH, LOW labeling
    axs.text(maxx + 0.5 * offsetx, 0.25 * maxy, "LOW", fontdict={}, rotation="vertical", va="center", ha="center")
    axs.text(maxx + 0.5 * offsetx, 0.75 * maxy, "HIGH", fontdict={}, rotation="vertical", va="center", ha="center")

    # x-axis HIGH, LOW labeling
    axs.text(0.25 * maxx, maxy + 0.5 * offsety, "HIGH", fontdict={}, va="center", ha="center")
    axs.text(0.75 * maxx, maxy + 0.5 * offsety, "LOW", fontdict={}, va="center", ha="center")

    # populate with dynamic datapoints
    # x_data, y_data = (5, 255, 2000), (0.2, 1.1, 95)
    # axs.scatter(x_data, y_data)

    buf = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
    data = base64.b64encode(buf.getbuffer()).decode("ascii")

    return f"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{data}'/>"
```

Note: I can't use pyplot because it is not recommended to be used for webapplications.

**Problem: If I now add data (uncomment 'populate with dynamic datapoints' section) it messes up the entire plot.** Also both axis need to have logarithmic scale.

Question: (select as you wish) 
A) How do I add dynamic scaling for the rectangles that are placed "outside" of the actual plot?
B) How do I detach the rectangles from axis scaling to give them a fixed spot?

Maybe I could just not show the axis-tick-labels of this plot and then add something like a second layer displaying the scatter data and "correct" axis-tick-labels?

Comment: You will want to define your non-data coordinates in terms of axes coordinates. See the [transformations tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for more details.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks a lot for the suggestion that what I am looking for is called "transformations" in the matplotlib realm. I found everything needed in the tutorial!